# Google scripts, change text in Form.html from Code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

In my Google Script I have 2 files: Form.html and Code.gs
When user click button in Form.html, the script start code in Code.gs, but I need inform user about process. 
How I can change text in Form.html from Code.gs?

Form.html crate in  Code.gs by this function:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form')
      .setTitle('Report');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

And Form.html have

```
<div id="report"></div>
```

For status report.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use templated HTML, see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Example:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Form');
  ui.message = "Hello!";
  ui = ui.evaluate().setTitle('Report');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

And in Form.html:

```
<div id="report"><?=message?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need to change <?=message?> in another function several times (it will be progress report). Now I see "UI not defined" error message.

Comment: in that case you must use client side Javascript (in Form.html) and return the data you want displayed from the .gs function(s). The client side Javascript would receive the response from the .gs function and update the message shown to the user.   This is significantly more complex so I won't have time to write up an example. Sorry!   See documentation on how to communicate with server functions here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication